# How to pass argument to javascript anonymous function

Tags: javascript

Can someone explain to me why x is undefined? Shouldn't be 123?

```
doSomething = (function(x) {
   alert(x)
})();

doSomething(123);
```

Comment: This is called IIFE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`doSomething` isn't a function.  It's `undefined`.

```
doSomething = (function(x) {
   alert(x)
})();
```

This declares an anonymous function, *immediately* executes it (that's what the `()` does), then sets `doSomething` to the return value - `undefined`.  Your anonymous function takes one parameter (`x`), but nothing is passed to it, so `x` is `undefined`.

You probably want this:

```
doSomething = function(x) {
   alert(x)
};

doSomething(123);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the parens, right now you define the function and immediately call it with an empty argument list.  Change it to this:

```
doSomething = function(x) {
   alert(x)
}
```

And then you can call it.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't this be the better way? let it init, then call it passing an argument?

```
doSomething = (function(x) {

    return(
            init = function(x){   

             alert(x)
            }
        )


})();

doSomething("test")
```

Comment: Now you're just making it more complicated.  Why are you making a *global* variable `init`?  Why does the main anonymous take a parameter `x`?  If you *really* wanted to do it this way, do this: `doSomething = (function(){ return function(x){ alert(x); }; })();`

Comment: What problem are you *actually* trying to solve here?  Why do you need to use an anonymous function that is auto-invoked?  Why not just `doSomething = function(x){ alert(x); };`?

Comment: one of my younger coworker developers has been wrapping all of his functions this way and i am trying to wrap my head around why. i never code this way but he insisted it was good practice? any explanation?

Comment: It's good practice *if* your functions are accessing variables outside their scope.  Like, if you are creating variables that your functions need, that aren't passed in.  This keeps them contained and out of the global scope. P.S. make sure to use `var` before your local vars!

Comment: Thanks for your help. if you could post an example of your last comment ("Like, if you are creating variables that your functions need, that aren't passed in. This keeps them contained and out of the global scope"), that would be great.

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have block scope, it has function scope.  So, IIFE's are used to create new scopes. (See: http://stage.learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/functions/#immediately-invoked-function-expression-iife)  They are used a lot in creating jQuery plugins, here's an example: http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/#protecting-the-alias-and-adding-scope  If you don't know jQuery, this might be confusing, but the point is to make a new scope, so that you can have variables only your function can use.

Comment: I would typically do something like:
var somescope = {};
somescope.doSomething = function(x){ alert(x) }

somescope.doSomething(123);

Comment: That works, but what if you wanted `doSomething` to access a variable `y` outside itself?  If your case, I guess you could do `somescope.y`.  Using IIFE's like in the link I posted is just a different way.

Comment: also, based on your comment couldnt i just change init to this.init inside my function?

Comment: `this` is only really used if you were doing `new doSomething()`.  It might not work as expected in your case.

Comment: I guess I just need to stick with what I have been doing all these years which exactly based on your answer. Thanks for your help.